# Find forces on cables of the cable car

Tags: calculus, physics

My Calc professor gave us a Physics problem. I'm absolutely awful at Physics. So here we go.

Here's the problem, plus my work and guess.

[image: cable_car_problem]

So I know my guess is wrong, but here's what I didn't get. I think I messed up on the angles. Also, I may have messed up getting both the tension values. I'm sure she's asking for me to get the sliding cable's tension too, but I didn't do that part yet. Please help!